# What USB cable do i need to my EOS 550D Canon camera to connect the camera to my laptop?

Tags: canon, canon-550d

what exactly type of cable do i need and is there any quality different between cables?

and i need a long cable. long i mean to be able to put the camera outside my car on a stand and still to be able to connect it to the laptop usb.

what i have tried so far is not so much . long time ago i had a cable but it was old and very very short.  I tried to google but no much help.

I want to be able to take photos when my camera is outside the car while the camera is still connected to my laptop with usb cable.

Answer (score 1):

USB isn't designed for long cable lengths; USB 2 as used by the 550D recommends/mandates a maximum cable length of 5m. You can chain up to 5 USB hubs, so this gives you up to 30m.

For more details, see [Maximum length of a USB Cable?](https://superuser.com/questions/64744/maximum-length-of-a-usb-cable) at Super User and the questions linked from there.

Comment: You can buy them 'ready chained' if you need to go over 5m. I have one to tether my Nikon, amongst other things. [eBay example link](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/312219227757)

Comment: No need to chain hubs.  You can easily buy "active USB" cables that go up to 100ft.   These contain driver electronics to and special cabling to extend the useful length, but typically do require external; power supplies to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the socket in the camera accepts a Mini-B plug (and could also accept another plug, that would in addition connect the video).